# What is the `flags` field for in canfd_frame in SocketCAN?

Tags: linux, can-bus, socketcan

A non-FD ("legacy") CAN frame has the following format in SocketCAN:

```
struct can_frame {
        canid_t can_id;  /* 32 bit CAN_ID + EFF/RTR/ERR flags */
        __u8    can_dlc; /* frame payload length in byte (0 .. 8) */
        __u8    __pad;   /* padding */
        __u8    __res0;  /* reserved / padding */
        __u8    __res1;  /* reserved / padding */
        __u8    data[8] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
};
```

The frame ID, length, and data all have clear places, plus some padding we don't worry about.  For a CAN-FD frame, though, there is an extra field:

```
struct canfd_frame {
        canid_t can_id;  /* 32 bit CAN_ID + EFF/RTR/ERR flags */
        __u8    len;     /* frame payload length in byte (0 .. 64) */
        __u8    flags;   /* additional flags for CAN FD */
        __u8    __res0;  /* reserved / padding */
        __u8    __res1;  /* reserved / padding */
        __u8    data[64] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
};
```

The `flags` field looks useful, but I have found no documentation as to what it actually holds.  Is it internal (i.e. set by the kernel)?  What are the possible flags, and what do they mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I found a bit of information here:

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/can.h#L112

```
/*
 * defined bits for canfd_frame.flags
 *
 * The use of struct canfd_frame implies the Extended Data Length (EDL) bit to
 * be set in the CAN frame bitstream on the wire. The EDL bit switch turns
 * the CAN controllers bitstream processor into the CAN FD mode which creates
 * two new options within the CAN FD frame specification:
 *
 * Bit Rate Switch - to indicate a second bitrate is/was used for the payload
 * Error State Indicator - represents the error state of the transmitting node
 *
 * As the CANFD_ESI bit is internally generated by the transmitting CAN
 * controller only the CANFD_BRS bit is relevant for real CAN controllers when
 * building a CAN FD frame for transmission. Setting the CANFD_ESI bit can make
 * sense for virtual CAN interfaces to test applications with echoed frames.
 */
```

If I understand this right, the ESI bit is only useful for testing on virtual CAN interaces.  The BRS bit is pretty low-level, though, and this does not specify whether the hardware will automatically set it or unset it.